# Getting the display text of the selected radio button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm populating a list radio buttons like below.

```
<td>
    @if (ViewBag.myList as System.Collections.IEnumerable != null)
    {
        foreach (var aType in new SelectList(ViewBag.myList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "Text", new { TabIndex = 0 }))
        {
            @Html.RadioButton("rdoMyList", aType.Value)
            @Html.Label(aType.Text)
        }
    }
</td>
```

I get the value of the selected radio button in jQuery like below.

```
var selectedValue = $.trim($("[id^='rdoMyList']:checked").val());
```

What I can't seem to figure out is getting the display text of the selected radio button.

Comment: Could you please show the actual HTML, and not the preprocessor code? Javascript acts on HTML, not what generated it.

Comment: If you mean the value of `aType.Text`, then use jQuery selectors to get the following `<label>` element and read the `text()` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by 'display text' you mean the text of the `label` element adjacent to the selected radio. For that you need to use `next()`. Try this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var $radio = $(this);
    var selectedValue = $radio.val();
    var labelText = $radio.next('label').text();

    // do something with your variables here...
});
```

You could improve the `input[type="radio"]` selector to narrow down the elements you want to target by adding a class to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this : add change event handler for radio button and get text of label adjucent to it.

**NOTE** - Assuming that label is next to every radio button

```
$(function(){
  $("[id^='rdoMyList']").change(function(){
     alert($(this).next('label').text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio button don't have text assigned. you can get the label text assign to the checked Radio button.

```
var text = $("input:checked + label").text();
```

The + signifies the adjacent selector. It will only select a label which has a checked input next to it.

Hope this helps